# How to implement collision detection in JQuery UI Slider component?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, slider, collision-detection

I have a project where I need a slider UI, the [Jquery slider](http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/#range) seems to do the job
but it seems that when I have a range slider, meaning two handles define a range:

[image]

I have the following problem:

I want the handles to have collision detection meaning that the handles do not touch each other, and do not overlap each other, and the values are calculated correctly, here is an exmple of what happens in the out of the box configuration.

[image]

I would like the slider to stop like this:

[image]

And the labels to read $62-$63

I know this exists,  I've seen it done with the plugin, what am I missing.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a [known bug](http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/3467) with an available patch. Also other user submissions relating to the topic.

Comment: How can I apply the patch to the minified version of JQuary UI?

Answer (score 2):

Add collision detection to slide-event when the slider is first created:

```
$('.selector').slider({
    // setup
    slide: function(evt, ui) {
        if (ui.values[0] >= ui.values[1])
        return false;
    }
});
```

This prevents the handles from colliding or overlapping.

Answer (score 0):

You can bind to the slide event and return false to prevent a slide

```
$( ".selector" ).bind( "slide", function(event, ui) {
    var values = $( ".selector" ).slider( "option", "values" );
    if (values[1] - values[0] < 10)
    return false;
});
```

Comment: OP still wants the numbers 1-off of each other, not within 10. (Which involves new logic that instead of using the whole slider's width/length as the value base, you use the slider's edge to the position of the other element (excluding width of the UI))